# Posting array variable in flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, serialization, encode

I want post with array variable but getting the following error:

> ConvException has occurred. JsonUnsupportedObjectError (erting object to an encodable object failed: _LinkedHashMap len:15)

My class:

```
  class Answer {
  int facility;
  String assesment_category;
  Map<int, dynamic> input = {};

  Answer(
      {this.facility,
      this.assesment_category,
      this.input});

  factory Answer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Answer(
        facility: map["facility"],
        assesment_category: map["assesment_category"],
        input: map["input"]);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "facility": facility,
      "assesment_category": assesment_category,
      "input": input
    };
  }
```

My post results:

```
"facility":1,
"assesment_category":"internal",
"input":{
   0:4,
   1:5,
}
```

If i don't use array variable it's working so i think there's a way to post if as an array

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrongly initialized the variable with Map, the correct initialization of array is

```
List<int> input = [];
```